# reformatting json output by adding an array

Tags: arrays, json, google-maps

I've json output like this:

> [{"id":5262130,"adres":"Apollo40","lat":"52.34985","lng":"4.88261","prijskaartje":"duur"}

It should be:

> [{"id":5262130,"adres":"Apollo40","location":{"lat":"52.34985","lng":"4.88261"},"prijskaartje":"duur"}

I just don't know how to?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two ways you could make an object that would create the desired JSON.

Create an object with all the properties in one go.

```
var jsObject = {
    id: 5262130,
    adres: "Apollo40",
    location: {
        lat: "52.34985",
        lng: "4.88261"
    },
    prijskaartje: "duur"
};

// JSON encode it.
var objectJSON = JSON.stringify(jsObject);
```

Create an object and then add your properties one by one.

```
var jsObject = {};

jsObject.id = 5262130;
jsObject.adres = "Apollo40";

jsObject.location = {};

jsObject.location.lat = "52.34985";
jsObject.location.lng = "4.88261";

jsObject.prijskaartje = "duur";

// JSON encode it.
var objectJSON = JSON.stringify(jsObject);
```

Since I don't know what your source for this information is this is the best I can do. If you give me more information about where you're the information you're encoding then I can potentially revise this answer.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Here's the [JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cg62d03a/).

Comment: at the moment I do a $json = json_encode( $result );
where $result = $db->query(SELECT..lat, lng,...WHERE...)
The result set contains n>50.
I don't want to do the reformatting in mysql, but in php.

Comment: Peter, I don't know why I assumed you were using Javascript that was very foolish of me. Is all that data coming from one SQL query?

Comment: see the answer to my own question. It's in php.

Answer (score 0):

ok, what I finally did in php is:
decode the original json, rewrite and encode to json:

```
$rewrite_json = json_decode($original_json, true);
$coordinates = array();
  foreach($rewrite_json as $key => $value) {
     $location[] = array('id'=>$value['id'],
     'adres'=>$value['adres'],
     'prijskaartje'=>$value['prijskaartje'],
     'location'=> array('lat' => (float)$value['lat'], 'lng' => (float)$value['lng']));
  }
$new_json = json_encode($location, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```